# Different AppDelegate and Storyboard files for different targets

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios-targets

I have an XCode Project(iOS App for only iPhones) and I want to use **same codebase** for publishing **different application**. I have to change icon, name and design for this second application. Therefore, I did not use Localization.

Also in codebase, I need some variables to hold different keywords for different targets.

Is there any way to do it or I have to clone same project and change this files after?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this question.

[StackOverFlow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40253702/how-to-set-different-appdelegate-for-different-targets-within-same-project)

You will have to convert the code to swift but this gives you the basics to get started.

Answer (score 1):

One workspace, two app targets, one set of code files.

Alternatively, use a framework. In that case it might be one workspace and two complete Xcode projects plus the framework.